# Do I need to master Hadoop before learning Mahout?

Tags: mahout

Do I need to master Hadoop before learning Mahout? How far I can go (in order to use data mining feature) without learning Hadoop ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Master? No. If you are using the parts of the project based on Hadoop then basic knowledge is required but sufficient. If you are using the parts not based on Hadoop then you don't need Hadoop at all.

Answer (score 1):

Mahout provides you with the instruments which will enable you to play with data mining. Yes, Mahout also supports Hadoop implementation incase the dataset is huge but it will fairly well without Hadoop on a single machine. Same code will work with or without Hadoop (Haddop will be picked up if Hadoop configuration parameter is set). Knowing Hadoop will add extra weapon to the kitty of Big Data.